# Is this an efficient way to convert HTML to text using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

I'm trying to convert HTML to plain text. Is it efficient? Am I missing something?

```
txt = $("body").find("script,noscript,style,:hidden").remove().end().text();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does the code in question give you the result you want? I think that's the only measure that matters. I tend to use tools like `lynx --dump` to get the text version of web pages - but client-side your technique seems fine.

Comment: What do you want to do that $('body').text() doesn't accomplish?

Comment: $('body').text() also returns the JS code inside <script> tags and the CSS directives inside <style> tags.

Comment: How about not ripping the DOM apart with `remove()`? Try the `:not` pseudo selector instead: `$("*:not(script,noscript,style,:hidden)").text()` which accomplishes the same thing if I understand you correctly.

Comment: This will not work correctly since text() works recursively and returns the text content of the element and all its children. So something like $("*").text() will get the same text content multiple times. You want to call text() with the top element only.

Comment: I guess this works if you can live with the fact that `text()` won't work for input elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML *is* text.

**EDIT**  Try this...

```
// Get current body text
var html = $("body").text();

// Create a new jQuery object out of body text and remove desired elements
var text = $(html).remove("script,noscript,style,:hidden").text();
```

Comment: I am looking for the plain text version of my HTML document.

Comment: Indeed, I eventually ended up doing something similar, since once you remove the elements it's basically impossible to plug them back. Now if only we had a recursive version of clone()...

Comment: You could use jQuery extend to do a deep copy like this: `var html = $.extend(true, {}, $("body").text());` and then have then use the same `var text` line in my answer. Try that, if it works as you expect, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Josh, you are basically copying a flat string (`$("body").text()`). Why use `extend(true,...)`? I ended up creating a jQuery.html2text function (based on `jQuery.text()`) specifically for converting from HTML.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your previous comment :D

Answer (score 0):

You want `element.textContent` (`element.innerText` for IE).

Answer (score 0):

```
var scriptContents = $('body').find('script').html();
var noScriptContents = $('body').find('noscript').html();
var styleContents = $('body').find('style').html();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to just render it to the screen you might be able to:

```
<pre>
    some html here
</pre>
```

Comment: I'm trying to use a client side script to convert HTML to plain text.

Comment: when you say plain tesxt do you mean you want to remove the tags?