# Find word using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a little piece of advice.
I have a test page with 2 fields: word number and URL
Also i have a button Push.
When i push the button i want to open the specified URL (it's local html files) and highlight the word at the "word number" position
Of course the code must ignore element nodes (`<p>`,`<b>`,`<table>` and so on)

Comment: Related: [Is this an efficient way to convert HTML to text using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830024/is-this-an-efficient-way-to-convert-html-to-text-using-jquery)

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "word number position" ? Lets say it is 3, should the third word in the HTML file be highlighted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#button_id').bind('click', function(e){
   var $wordat  = $('#input_id_word').val(),
       $url     = $('#input_id_url').val(),
       counter  = 0;

   $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: $url,
      dataType: 'html',
      success:  function(data){
          $(data).find('body').contents().each(function(i, e){
              var wordarr = $(e).text().split(" ");

              counter += wordarr.length;

              if($wordat <= counter){
                 wordarr[$wordat] = "<span style='background-color: red;'>" + wordarr[$wordat] + "</span>";                     
              }

              $(e).text(wordarr.join(" "));
          });

          $('element_id_to_insert').html(data);
      }
   });
});
```

This is untested and can get improved like a lot, but something very similar to this should do it.

Comment: @Felix. Exactly this i want to do. If i have 
<p>This is <b><u>TEST</u></b> the word that is highlighted will be TEST (for number = 3).
@jAndy. 
i got a js error (in FF error console) s.url is undefined ... error is in jquery.js
Thanks

Comment: I made a little research. First of all i have a old version of jquery.js. I update it at newest version. Now i don't have any errors in console but nothing it's displayed. Thanks

Comment: nobody write here for almost 1 day.
i discover the problems from the script above
1. $(data).find('body').contents().each(function(i, e) - doesn't work
2. wordarr[$wordat] = "<span style='background-color: red;'>" + wordarr[$wordat] + "</span>";  this is correct but jquery doesn't take this as a html code
If anyone can help me with this 2 problem i will be very happy :)
Thanks